# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@74507f79

Tags: android, kotlin

i was cleaned my string resources and anything, i checked all the xml files but nothing odd.But i still get this error

> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file I:\Kotlin\Dicoding\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@356d7542.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3152e737.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@74507f79.). Check logs for more details.

here is my code

https://github.com/fahriamura/Dicoding